# Not getting the expected output

Tags: c++

I am writing a homework assignment that asks for the user to read in a text file that contains an unknown number of SSNs and grades. The program then needs to compute the max, min and average scores, then output the max grade with the associated SSN as well as the min and avg grades.

It seems to operate correctly but the output is all "0".

Any help fixing this is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string ssn, maxSSN;
    int grade = 0, totalGrades = 0, count = 0, maxScore = 0, minScore = 0;
    double avgScore = 0;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\\lab5a.txt");

    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening the requested file\n\n";
        system("pause");
        return 101;
    }



    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            maxScore = grade;
            minScore = grade;
        }
        else
        {
            if (grade > maxScore)
                maxScore = grade;
            if (grade < minScore)
                minScore = grade;
        }
            grade += totalGrades;
            count++;

    }

    if (count)
        avgScore = totalGrades / count;

    cout << "Maximum Score: " << maxScore << "      Student SSN:" << maxSSN << "\n";
    cout << "Minimum Score: " << minScore << "\n";
    cout << "Average Score: " << avgScore << "\n";
    // studentFile >> ssn >> grade;

    inFile.close();

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `totalGrades` is never modified during the "file read" loop.

Comment: You never read the file.  Is that really your code, because it looks to me like it would never complete...?

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site. Too localized.

Answer (score 3):

**1.You are not reading anything from `inFile`. Most likely, you want to read the grade value:**

```
 while (!inFile.eof())
 {
     inFile >> grade;
     ...
```

According to the feedback from @Blastfurnace, using `inFile.eof()` is also wrong. Consider the following input file:

```
3
5
9
17
```

where each line is terminated with `lf`. Then, the loop will read **5 lines** since it does not detect the end of file **after** the value `17` has been read, but will try to read another value from the file. `count` will then be `5` when the loop terminates, which is wrong.

Use the following condition instead:

```
 while (inFile >> grade)
 {
   ...
```

To also read the ssn, use this:

```
while (inFile >> ssn >> grade)
{
   ...
```

This ensures that both `ssn` and `grade` have been read from the file when executing the loop body.

**2.The calculation of the `totalGrades` has the operands in the wrong order:**

```
 grade += totalGrades;
```

needs to be

```
 totalGrades += grade;
```

**3.You have declared `avgScore` as double, but**

```
 avgScore = totalGrades / count;
```

does integer arithmetic, so that you will never get a floating point result. You need to cast at least one operand to double:

```
 avgScore = totalGrades / (double) count;
```

**4.What is still missing is the handling of the SSN**

You need to read it along with the grade from the file, and then assign it to `maxSSN` at the same place where you assign the `maxScore` value.

Comment: Please don't tell beginners to loop on `eof()`. [It's a bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: I did not, its from the question ;)

Comment: How about telling him to do `while (infile >> grade) {}` instead?

Comment: Definitely good feedback, thanks for the link - I will update my answer

Comment: +1 Looping on `eof()` is a common, and confusing, source of errors when people are learning how to use iostreams.

Comment: @Andreas - That help alot! I am not sure how to read in the data since it is formatted like 123456789 97 . Do I use a getline? How do I handle differentiating between the SSN and the grade?

Comment: I have updated my answer - I assumed that `123456789` is the ssn and `97` is the grade

Answer (score 0):

You are **not reading** the file and hence not taking `grade` as an **input**.